# Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

After I stopped handling my clicks with a handleClick function which was outside the useEffect hook i get the following error:

Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

Is it not possible to handleClicks like I tried below?

These are my stateful components

```
  const [value, setValue] = useState([])
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  const [buttonValue, setButton] = useState(false)
```

This is my useEffect Hook

```
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/').then(res => setValue(res.data))

    if (buttonValue === 'delete') {
      setLoading(true)
      axios.delete('http://localhost:5000/delete').then(() => {
        setLoading(false)
        setButton(null)
      })
    } else if (buttonValue === 'create') {
      setLoading(true)
      axios.post('http://localhost:5000/').then(() => {
        setLoading(false)
        setButton(null)
      })
    }
  }, [isLoading])
```

These are my Buttons

```
     <Form.Group>
        <Button variant='success' className='button' onClick={setButton('create')} id='create'>Create Sales Order</Button>
      </Form.Group>
      <Form.Group>
        <Button variant='danger' className='button' onClick={setButton('delete')} id='delete'>Delete Sales Order</Button>
      </Form.Group>
    </Form
```

Comment: `onClick={setButton('delete')}` you're calling the function instead of passing it as the prop's value. `onClick={() => setButton('delete')}`

Comment: Now the error is gone but nothing happens when I press the buttons

Comment: Then try `onClick={(e) => {e.preventDefault(); setButton('delete');}}`

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this also does not work

Comment: In the last line of `useEffect`  you reference `[isLoading]` which means that the effect will only run if `isLoading` changes, you may want to change it to `[buttonValue]`